# How do I create star shape for avatar image?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I want to create star shape for user avatar image.
I do not know how to fill image in such shape.

My code:

```css
#star {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #05ed08;
  position: relative;
}
#star:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid #05ed08;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 30px;
  left: -50px;
}
&#60;
```

```html
<div id="star"></div>
```

I want an image here between div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want an image here between div.

There are a couple of ways in which the above statement can be interpreted - (1) You want to fill the shape with an image, restrict the image to the shape's boundaries and clip any extra part or (2) you just want to place an image on top of the star.

---

**For Case 1:** If you need to create such complex shapes and also have an image fill to it then the best option for it is to ***use SVG instead of CSS***.

SVG allows for better control over the shape, keeps the image within the shape's boundaries and also restricts the hover (hit area) to the shape's boundaries.

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
path {
  fill: url(#g-image);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
  <defs>
    <pattern id='g-image' width='100' height='100' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'>
      <image xlink:href='https://placeimg.com/100/100/animals' width='100' height='100' />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path d='M0,25 L33,25 50,0 66,25 99,25 75,50 99,75 66,75 50,100 33,75  0,75 25,50z' />
</svg>
```

---

**For Case 2:** Or if you are just looking to ***place an image*** on top of the shape then you could use the CSS given in question itself and just place an image absolutely on top of it. Few things that would be worth noting are (1) It is very tough to make shapes created using border such as these method be responsive (2) The image should have fixed height and width, if not there is every chance that it will overflow and be  visible outside the star shape also.

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#star {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 200px solid #05ed08;
  position: relative;
}
#star:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-top: 200px solid #05ed08;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 60px;
  left: -100px;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div id='star'></div>
  <img src='http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals' />
</div>
```